# mysql_query() always returns True despite entering False information

Tags: php, mysql

There is code to check if the user has entered the right password or not.

```
if (isset($_POST['userpassword']))
{
    include('db.php');
    //I have used the name passwordu instead of password in the database as well.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_REQUEST['username']."' AND passwordu = '".md5($_REQUEST['userpassword'])."';";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result){ //THIS IS WHERE I FEEL THE ERROR IS
        echo "Congratulations. You are now Logged in. You will be logged out when the Browser is closed.";
        $_SESSION['logval'] = TRUE; //Sets the User Logged in for the complete session.
    }
    else echo "Sorry, You Entered Wrong Info.";
}
```

However, even if a wrong password is entered it accepts the log in.

What is wrong here?
Also, if I am making a conceptual mistake, please tell me the right way to check if the user has entered the right information.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Stop it.  Just...stop.  `mysql_query` has been at least unofficially deprecated for years.  What half-assed site or book taught you to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be completely honest - what is wrong is the code is allowing [MySQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

But for your code, use mysql_num_rows().

mysql_query() returns true if the query was successful.  false if not.
mysql_num_rows() counts the rows.

```
if ( mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("some query")) == 1 ) { logged in }
```

Comment: And a successful query can still affect/return 0 rows.  If i `update...where x=1`, and no record has x=1, that query's still successful even though it did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

A query results in true if the query succeeds even if no records were returned. Check the number of records returned instead.

Answer (score 1):

change `if ($result)` to `if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `;` from the end of query, it's not necessary.

```
... md5($_REQUEST['userpassword'])."';";
                                     ^---this one
```

Comment: Done that. But, it does not help.

Answer (score -1):

Well it returns an empty set, but returns, in situations like these, I prefer this

```
$query=<<<HERE
SELECT count(*) as count form users where username=" " and password=" "
HERE;
$send=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($send);
$count=$row["count"];
if($count=="0"){// not logged in}
else if($count=="1"){//logged in}
```

check the count value and then provide login
and stop using mysql_query, switch to pdo

Answer (score -3):

Change

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_REQUEST['username']."' AND passwordu = '".md5($_REQUEST['userpassword'])."';";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username == '".$_REQUEST['username']."' AND passwordu == '".md5($_REQUEST['userpassword'])."';";
```

The `=` and `==` operators are not the same. `==` is a comparisation operator that means *is the same as* and `=` although it means *equals* but cannot mean that.

Also change

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

to

```
$result = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
```

Your query will always return true because it executed successfully, regardless of whether any rows were found to exist or not.

Comment: SQL recognises=as comparison operator. theres no assigning in sql

Comment: SQL only recognises = as a comparision operator, when you are using it once. When you use it twice in your query, it fails.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: The 1 equals is doing it wrong! It works in some instances, and not in others. I have been coding in php for years, and many many times I have had a query fail because it used `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: -1 for `==` in MySQL.  You use `=` to compare things in MySQL.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal

Comment: @desbest: Then you probably weren't using MySQL, or you were doing something else wrong.

Comment: @desbest: SQL is not PHP.  `=` is the only standard operator for testing equality.  I'm not even seeing `==` listed in the manual.