# php code stops working suddenly. strange Behaviour?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I built a code for Log In Page. The Code was working perfectly till yesterday. But, today it is not working like i wanted it to work. Its on my localhost at the moment.

```
if (isset($_POST['userpassword']))
        {
            include('db.php'); //I am using passwordu instead of password.
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_REQUEST['username']."' AND passwordu = '".md5($_REQUEST['userpassword'])."'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($num_rows == 1)
            {
                echo "Congratulations. You are now Logged in. You will be logged out when the Browser is closed.";
                $_SESSION['logval'] = TRUE;
            }
            else
            { 
                            echo "You Have Entered Wrong Information. <b>Please Try AGAIN."; }
?>
```

Whenever I enter a wrong password, it shows the correct thing. But, when i enter the right password, then also it shows that the password was not accepted.

This code was working perfectly till yesterday. Today, this problem cropped up.

**I Have Figured out the Solution to this problem.**

I was using the varchar(20) for the passwordu field. So, it was not working. I set it now to a larger value i.e. 100(for safety). And it works like a charm.

Comment: The code has NEVER been working 'fine'. You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: is it `passwordu` or `password` in query?

Comment: I am aware of that. But, i am a begginer, and i am just looking to understand the basics.

Comment: You are sure that the column name for password is 'passwordu'? Looks weird to me.

Comment: This question was never one. strange Behaviour?

Comment: @Raidenace, it is passwordu only.

Comment: Also from the wording of your question, I think the issue is today. Try on another day if it works then again, too.

Comment: No Error Message. When, i just checked the `mysql_num_rows` function returns `ZERO` on entering correct information as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One glaring issue that I see is that you are checking if `$num_rows == 1`.  While this is fine in most cases, it's possible that it is masking a potential issue with duplicate accounts.  This is to say that if you have more than 1 of the same account, you give the illusion that the credentials are incorrect when in fact they are.

As a test, try the example below to see if it begins to work:

```
if ($num_rows >= 1)
{
   //Correct info
}
else
{
   //Incorrect info
}
```

Though this may fix your problem, you will need to figure out why you would have a duplicate account.

*Edit*

I would consider Mike Brant's suggestion in the comments below.  Truly, there should be a unique constraint to prevent the potential case for duplicates.

Comment: If you really consider to help the OP, you might want to go his history of questions to salvage it for more information, e.g. one of those questions is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588404/mysql-query-function-always-returning-true-despite-entering-false-information

Comment: This is a good suggestion here to check your database for duplicates.  I would suggest however that, instead of looking for `$num_rows >= 1`, that you make a unique index on username & passwordu to prevent duplicate DB entries and still check for `$num_rows === 1`

Comment: Agreed @MikeBrant.  I wouldn't do this personally, but hopefully this will be one of those *d'oh!* moments for him.

Comment: Well, i have personally made a database with only 2 entries. just to test.

Comment: And what was the result?  Did the 2 entries include the same username/password?

Comment: No, they were different.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a vague situation, and based on the code snippet posted it is very difficult to determine what is wrong (The snippet as such seems correct), and you have also said it was working until yesterday.

The first thing to do is try some debugging. Apparently this condition is not returning true:

`if ($num_rows == 1)`

So first do a `die("num_rows = ".$num_rows);` to check what value it is returning. Post it here and we can go further from there.

Comment: Please take into account that this question is likely a follow up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588404/mysql-query-function-always-returning-true-despite-entering-false-information which never had got an accepted answer. You might find additional information in there that you should compile into your answer so that you can better understand the problem of OP.

Comment: The Value Being Returned is ZERO.

Comment: There you go, you do not have a record in the database with the username and password you are entering. Check the db to make sure it exists.

Comment: Yes, I checked the DB. I checked the username. password is encrypted so i can not understand it. I think the error is in the query.

Comment: I dont think the error is in the query since you said nothing was changed and it was running yesterday right? I dont think the code "rewrote" itself. Why dont you create a new user with a username/password you KNOW and then try logging in with it?

Comment: Sir, I have already done all that process.

Comment: Sorry dude, you are confusing me. You said that you cannot understand the password. And I dont know what all process you did, so all the best.

Comment: I said, in Database the username is showing as : rohit and the pasword as: lao48tuxq97mstq48m98y which is encrypted. 

Secondly, i created a new log in, from a Sign up page i have made. The sign up page itself encrypts the password and saves it in database.